# Process wont run

Tags: centos7

I have a piece of data management software that I cannot seem to get to run. Whenever I start the process it gives me this

```
[root@001 install]# bash niagarad_generic start
Starting Niagara Daemon: [  OK  ]
```

but when I check the status I get

```
[root@001 install]# bash niagarad_generic status
niagarad is stopped
```

How do I tell why the service is not starting?

I ran it in debug mode and this is what I got

```
[root@001 install]# Niagara-3.8.41bash -x niagarad_generic start
-bash: Niagara-3.8.41bash: command not found
[root@001 install]# bash -x niagarad_generic start
+ DAEMON=/bin/niagarad
+ PROG='Niagara Daemon'
+ SERVICE_NAME=naxd
+ PIDDIR=/var/run/niagarad
+ PIDFILE=/var/run/niagarad/niagarad.pid
+ REDHAT=false
+ DEBIAN=false
+ '[' -f /etc/init.d/functions ']'
+ . /etc/init.d/functions
++ TEXTDOMAIN=initscripts
++ umask 022
++ PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
++ export PATH
++ '[' 676 -ne 1 -a -z '' ']'
++ /bin/mountpoint -q /cgroup/systemd
++ /bin/mountpoint -q /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
++ case "$0" in
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ COLUMNS=80
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -c /dev/stderr -a -r /dev/stderr ']'
+++ /sbin/consoletype
++ CONSOLETYPE=pty
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -f /etc/sysconfig/i18n -o -f /etc/locale.conf ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
++ unset LANGSH_SOURCED
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -f /etc/sysconfig/init ']'
++ . /etc/sysconfig/init
+++ BOOTUP=color
+++ RES_COL=60
+++ MOVE_TO_COL='echo -en \033[60G'
+++ SETCOLOR_SUCCESS='echo -en \033[0;32m'
+++ SETCOLOR_FAILURE='echo -en \033[0;31m'
+++ SETCOLOR_WARNING='echo -en \033[0;33m'
+++ SETCOLOR_NORMAL='echo -en \033[0;39m'
++ '[' pty = serial ']'
++ __sed_discard_ignored_files='/\(~\|\.bak\|\.orig\|\.rpmnew\|\.rpmorig\|\.rpmsave\)$/d'
++ '[' '' = 1 ']'
+ REDHAT=true
+ DEBIAN=false
+ LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/niagarad
+ '[' '!' -d /var/run/niagarad ']'
+ true
+ . /etc/sysconfig/network
++ NETWORKING=yes
++ GATEWAYDEV=venet0
++ NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
++ IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=venet0
+ '[' yes = no ']'
+ '[' root '!=' niagarad ']'
+ SUDO_REQUIRES_TTY=true
+ true
+ '[' root = root ']'
+ cat /etc/sudoers
+ grep '^Defaults.*\!requiretty'
+ cat /etc/sudoers
+ grep '^Defaults.*requiretty'
+ SUDO_REQUIRES_TTY=true
+ HAS_TTY=false
+ tty -s
+ '[' -t 0 ']'
++ who
+ WHO_OUTPUT='root     pts/0        2016-01-07 14:54 (dhcp-d0-3-4b-d1-33-5a.cpe.wightman.ca)'
+ '[' 78 '!=' 0 ']'
+ HAS_TTY=true
+ true
+ true
+ sudo -u niagarad /usr/bin/niagaradctl start
Starting Niagara Daemon: [  OK  ]
+ exit 0
```

Comment: anything in logs?

Comment: How exactly do I check the logs exactly? Stupid I know, I am newer to CentOS.

Comment: Logs will generally be under `/var/log` - there might be a Niagara specific file there. Since there's nothing obviously wrong at the system level it might be best to take this up with the vendor's support team (or at least check vendor specific documentation/support channels).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try running it with:

```
bash -x niagarad_generic start
```

This will enable debugging.

Comment: I ran it in debug mode and edited the details of this above. I don't really understand as to what it is telling me though.